# VBA loop with automatic saving; code will do first instance but then generates blanks after perpetually

Tags: excel, vba

I've got an excel doc with 2 tabs. A [data tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3bLX.jpg) and a [template tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5Q6S.jpg). The data tab contains data in chunks equally spaced apart starting in row 52 (for this situation there's only three chunks). I want my code to copy some cells (the ones in gold) and paste it into the template tab. Then duplicate the template tab in another workbook to be saved and closed. Then it would go back to the original workbook and do the [next chunk of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Nrz0.jpg) in the data tab till the end of all possible data (which will vary week over week, so like next week there could be 10 chunks).

Without the 'make new workbook and save' part of the code I can see it properly copy-pasting/cycling through to the end on my Template tab. So if it's plain like this, the data on the Template tab when done it's exactly the same as the last data set in the Data tab (aka the third chunk of the three total chunks of data with France + Nice). But when I add the new workbook+save feature it will properly do the 1st data chunk but then rapidly spirals into generating [a bunch of empty excel docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnwKs.jpg) that I have to ESC out of or will will never stop making them.

```
Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long   

Set fnc = Sheets("France")
Set st = Sheets("Template")   

lastRow = fnc.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 

For i = 52 To lastRow
    st.Range("B30").Value = fnc.Range("B" & i).Value
    st.Range("C30").Value = fnc.Range("C" & i).Value
    st.Range("D33").Value = fnc.Range("D" & i + 3).Value
    st.Range("E33").Value = fnc.Range("E" & i + 3).Value            
    st.Range("F33").Value = fnc.Range("F" & i + 3).Value            
    st.Range("G33").Value = fnc.Range("G" & i + 3).Value            
    st.Range("H33").Value = fnc.Range("H" & i + 3).Value      

Sheets("Template").Select
Sheets("Template").Copy
Sheets("Template").Name = "True Template"

If Dir("C:\Users\Edamame\Desktop\True Template", vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir ("C:\Users\Edamame\Desktop\True Template")
End If

ChDir ("C:\Users\Edamame\Desktop\True Template") ' Makes it save to the folder
Filename = "FW" & Format(Date, "ww") & "_" & Range("D30") & "_" & Range("B30") & "_True Template_" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

ActiveWorkbook.Close False  

Windows("Wine.xlsb").Activate 
Next i
```

Comment: Are you sure that populating your template in your loop goes as you intended? Seems to me you using empty cells to populate `B30` and `C30` if you go from `52 to lastRow`. Try to include a `Step 10` and check if that would work (`For i = 52 To lastRow Step 10`). I have not checked the rest of your code.

Comment: Right now you have (1) For i ... (2) Copying ... (3) Saving ..  (4) Next i. Would changing the order and removing the saving from the loop solve your issue? (1) For i ... (2) Copying ... (3) Next i (4) Saving ..

Comment: Also, whilst I don't think it's the problem here, more common practice would be to set a workbook object to refer to instead of using `Windows("Wine.xlsb").Activate`. Any good reason why not to use a `xlsm` extention btw?

Comment: @JvD, yes I just checked again and commented-out everything between+including Sheets("Template").Select and Windows("Wine.xlsb").Activate . I cleared my template and ran the macro. It populated the template and finished with all the info from the last chunk about France + Nice. | I don't set the workbook as an object because the file will actually change names every week. This is just a babyified version of what I am actually trying to work on. I use xlsb b/c it takes up less space on the computer. We are not given much HD space (I've been here 1 month and it's half full already).

Comment: @simple-solution, changing the order will not solve it as a major step is duplicating the worksheet in a brand new workbook. The brand new workbook is what's saved. It cannot save a workbook that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @JvdV, you're STEP 10 thing absolutely worked! It has now generated the individual .xlsx template files all perfectly. SOLVED! You da bomb homie.

Comment: @JvdV, I'm a super newbie but I think you need to resubmit your response in the "Your Answer" section so that I can check-mark it to 'accept' it so my question can close and you can get Stack Overflow points. If that's not right please let me know what I should do to make sure you get full credit for solving this problem!

Comment: Glad that solved it, posted an answer to close the thread :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment:

Seems to me you are using empty cells to populate B30 and C30 if you go from 52 to lastRow. Try to include a `Step 10` and check if that would work.

```
For i = 52 To lastRow Step 10
```